# Selenium + Proxy = Fail

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

Proxy not working in Selenium

First of all i use free proxys from proxyfish (maybe thats the problem alrdy) https://hidemyna.me/en/proxy-checker/ tells me theyre working.

I found lots of code/solutions, most is outdated (capabilities=options..) or not working for me.

Tried several code/proxys chrome/ff however https://www.iplocation.net/ and https://whatismyipaddress.com showing actual IP address (IPv4 and IPv6).

What I tried..

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
System.getProperties().put("74.208.112.***", "8080");  //1st try
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("74.208.112.***:8080");    //2nd try
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
options.setProxy(proxy);
options.addArguments("--proxy-server=74.208.112.***:8080");  //3rd try
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.iplocation.net/");
driver.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com/");
```

Solution:

```
proxy.setSslProxy("74.208.112.***:8080");
```

Is there a way to test proxy connection before using proxy?